# What is the differences between 'ready' and 'on'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

(i)

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
 $(".edit-item").on('click', function ()     
  {    
    //something    
  }    
});
```

(ii)

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit-item', function () {        
     //something        
 });
```

Why the first one is called at only once.but the second one is called twice.

what is the technical issue of second one(ii).

Any one help me?

Comment: Where are you calling the second one twice?

Comment: Have you read the docs of `ready` and `on`? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually jquery **.ready()** is triggered  when all the DOM elements are loaded on the browser, **.on()** is an event delegate that assign events to DOM elements at run time. It is a good approach to assign the events (i.e. delegation) at **ready()**. can you fiddle the sample for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Both are binding events:

1. First one normal binding of events.
2. Second one is event bind using delegated-events approach.

Learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code and it was invoked only once. Like Bergi's comment, you should be calling second one (ii) twice.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-item', function () {        
     //something        
 });
```